# Retrieving callback value from calling function. How to?

Tags: javascript

In a function I make an ajax call, the call back has the response_text I need in that function.  I tried the obvious of putting a `var here` in the calling function and using it in the callback function.  This does not work.  Next I tried using a `function out()` which is how I've done this before.  This works as I can now access response_text from out().  However, is there a way to access from `vOrb()` directly, that is, the original calling function?

I don't want to place all the code in the call back as in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784702/retrieving-value-from-javascript-callback-function)

Would the module pattern work as a way to keep `var here` in scope when the callback function make its asynchronous return? Or would simply writing `var vOrb = function(){}` as a wrap and call using new, do the trick?

```
function vOrb( icon_array )
{
    var here; // does not work
    function out( here ){} // does work
    new AjaxRequest().invoke( 'ajax_type=fav_dir', function( response_text )
    {
        out( response_text );
    } ); 

// want response_text here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if I understood everything right but I’ll try to answer anyway.
If this is what you want, you can't use response_text outside your callback - it would be undefined.

It’d be better to proceed like so :

```
function vOrb( icon_array )
{
    new AjaxRequest().invoke( 'ajax_type=fav_dir', myCallback ); 
    var myCallback = function ( response_text ) {
        // blah…
    };
}
```

If you absolutely want to use response_text outside your callback, then you'll have to check if it is set first.

```
var my_response;
function vOrb( icon_array )
{
    new AjaxRequest().invoke( 'ajax_type=fav_dir', myCallback ); 
    var myCallback = function ( response_text ) {
        my_response = response_text;
    };
}

// ...

if ( typeof my_response !== 'undefined' ) { // will only work after the callback is triggered
    // use "my_response" here
}
```

Comment: I mentioned the first method in my question...the second method is interesting but I think that b.c. the call back is asychronous, my_response...will always be undefined...unless the ajax call can complete in less than one step...explains the error message I was geting earlier though.

Comment: Indeed, you can't avoid using a callback. I realized seconds after posting my answer that the `typeof my_response !== 'undefined'` condition would always be false, unless you put `my_response` in a more global scope. Anyway, my second proposition makes very litte sense - use the variable in a callback.

Comment: ...so that would be another way to do it.